# Kubernetes pods not updating

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, gitlab, cicd

I have 3 nodes in Google Cloud Plataform with Kubernetes engine and i have a .gital-ci.yml file that update the pods. All apparently works fine, i just have an index.html to be updated and when i check it in the server, its updated. My problem is that when i try to access the external ip with the port, the index.html is not updated. I read something about cache, and i tried to run the command **kubectl rollout restart deploy app**, but it didn't work.
I don't know if it is useful, but to access the page i needed to release the firewall by using this command: **gcloud compute firewall-rules create cd-cd-kube --allow tcp:30005**

HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>App version 2.1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>App 2.1</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

.gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy_gcp

build_images: 
  stage: build
  image: docker:20.10.16

  services:
    - docker:20.10.16-dind
  
  variables:
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"
  
  before_script:
    - docker login -u $REGISTRY_USER -p $REGISTRY_PASS 

  script:
    - docker build -t guirms/app-cicd-dio:1.0 app/.
    - docker push guirms/app-cicd-dio:1.0

deploy_gcp: 
  stage: deploy_gcp

  before_script:
    - chmod 400 $SSH_KEY  
    
  script:
    - ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i $SSH_KEY gcp@$SSH_SERVER "sudo rm -Rf ./ci-cd-kubernetes/ && sudo git clone https://gitlab.com/guirms/ci-cd-kubernetes.git && cd ci-cd-kubernetes && sudo chmod +x ./script.sh && ./script.sh"
```

deployment.yml file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app
  labels:
    app: app
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: app
        image: guirms/app-cicd-dio:1.0
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - targetPort: 80
      port: 80
      nodePort: 30005
  selector:
    app: app
```

script.sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash

kubectl apply -f deployment.yml
```

dockerfile file:

```
FROM httpd:latest

WORKDIR /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/

COPY index.html /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/

EXPOSE 80
```

Comment: based on my previous answer a kubectl rollout restart is definitely needed to pull the latest image on the server side as your image version is always same. Also including this your HTML may be getting cached by browser. Try two things one use incognito mode and test secondly use a random query parameter in your HTML url access say http://your-node-ip:node-port?random=put-a-random-number-here-each-time. This will let us know if this is a browser caching issue

Comment: I already did it, im sure that the problem is on kubernetes side

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure that the image you put in the Kubernetes manifest is the same as expected. You can pull it locally and run to see what you have inside, e.g.:

```
docker run --entrypoint=sh -it guirms/app-cicd-dio:1.0
```

With this command, you will be shared with the container. Then you can `cat` index.html to double check that version `1.0` contains the index.html you need.

2. If 1 is OK, try `kubectl rollout` or `kubectl delete` and then `kubectl apply`. Due to your `pullPolicy: Always`, the image must be pulled.
3. If still old index.html, try to clear the cache in your browser or simply try another (better, freshly new, and better in incognito mode) browser you've never opened this site by.